# How are boundary conditions considered in PDEs?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, mathematical-modeling

I'm new to numerical modeling and trying to figure out how things work inside business codes.

Consider a 1D domain divided into small cells of width dx and at the East and West a Neumann conditions boundary is affected (zero flow in the East and constant in the West). In the center, we have an upward outgoing flow. Here is an illustration image:

[problem illustration image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9uQ4.png)

The PDE governing this problem is given by the following:

[PDE governing the problem and BC conditions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9F5x.png)

Questions

1. The model is in 1D and the flow w is done along the fictitious axis y. How do we define it as a boundary condition in our model?
2. Are the defined boundary conditions calculated independently of the PDEP or should they be incorporated into the discrete form of the EDP as below (example with q2)?

[BC at the Western coin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VERN4.png)

3. I also question the correctness of the formulation of the condition on qa. Indeed, it is an outgoing flow towards the outside (thus according to the fictitious axis y). Is my way of writing it correct?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Someone to help?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE!  You are generally more likely to get a positive response if you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead of attaching images (images are not searchable or readable by a screen reader).  Additionally, you should try to [avoid posting a question with multiple questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#33671) and whenever possible either consolidate your questions into one or be prepared to post a sequence of separate posts.